# SetTimeOut in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I was wondering if the following code could introduce race conditions:

```
 rows.each(function () {

        var current = this;
        var doOperation = function () {
            current.someMethod();      
            // do some operation using current
        };

        setTimeout(doOperation, 1);
    });
```

During the settimeout delay, is it possible that the browser will start executing the next itteration of the loop and change "current", so that doOperation doesn't exuecute using the value that was orignally assigned?

Comment: 1 ms is VERY little time

Comment: I am doing it to prevent the IE 8.0 stop long running script message. Since the whole loop will take some time to finish

Comment: You can use zero instead of one.

Comment: Actually there's a minimum delay of 4 ms : http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no danger there, because each iteration's `doOperation` will close over a new `current` local variable, not interfering with previous ones.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense. Each iteration of the "each" is executed inside its own closure

Answer (score 3):

Everything seems to be in order here. `setTimeout` is in the closure of the `each` function, so its `doOperation` will be different for each row you have.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense. Each iteration of the "each" is executed inside its own closure